# Using SQL and AD membership providers together in ASP.NET 4.5

Tags: asp.net, authentication, sqlmembershipprovider, activedirectorymembership

I have an application that is used by both internal employees and outside clients.  I would like internal users to be authenticated against Active Directory, while clients use the Universal Providers membership provider.

I'm vaguely familiar with how to set up multiple membership providers, but what I'm not sure of is the best way to determine which provider to authenticate a user against.  Is this a common scenario and if so, is there a standard approach to handling it?

Comment: You could check each provider to see if their username exists.  Then auto log them in if they exist in one. If they exist in both, then pop up a dialog asking them which one to use (or just default to one or the other).

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar.  However we used "Forms Authentication".  In the Login.aspx.cs we first try to authenticate against Active Directory and if that fails then we go against a SQL database.  It was much simpler in my eyes to do it this way.